# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): Android

Tags: android, sqlite, media-queries

I need to get phone Media data for custom app and i used query, but it shows error for some Android devices here my code and show syntax error only some devices.

````
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        String[] PROJECTION_BUCKET = {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MINI_THUMB_MAGIC};
        String BUCKET_GROUP_BY =
                "2) GROUP BY 2,(3";
        String BUCKET_ORDER_BY = "MAX(datetaken) DESC";

        // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
        Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(
                images, PROJECTION_BUCKET, BUCKET_GROUP_BY, null, BUCKET_ORDER_BY);
        cursor.moveToNext();




        String selection = "WHERE "+MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID+" = 1030343353";

        return new CursorLoader(getContext(), uri, PROJECTION_BUCKET, BUCKET_GROUP_BY, null, BUCKET_ORDER_BY);
    }```

and here error 

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT _id, bucket_id, bucket_display_name, datetaken, _data, mini_thumb_magic FROM images WHERE ((is_pending=0) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' )) AND (_data>'')) AND ((2) GROUP BY 2,(3)) ORDER BY MAX(datetaken) DESC
````

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy fix to your problem. If you look here [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String)), you will notice that:

- You are trying to pass "group by" stuff into field that `formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself)`
- There is no such thing as "group by" for the specific query you are using

Your syntax error can easily be fixed but I'm afraid the result will not be what you expect. You should change your query strategy to something else, may be like raw query.

Comment: i want to get media from phone as a albums